# Bell inequality - Classical prediction in his original proof

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

In Bell's original paper in which he first states his inequality

$|P(\vec a,\vec b) - P(\vec a,\vec c)|\le 1 + P(\vec b,\vec c)$

he writes just after stating it: "Unless P is constant, the left hand side is in general of order $|\vec b-\vec c|$ for small $|\vec b-\vec c|$. Thus $P(\vec b,\vec c)$ can not be stationary at the minimum value ($-1$ at $\vec b = \vec c$) and can not equal the quantum mechanical predicition."

How can he estimate the order of the term? I can not reproduce this statement.

Comment: The paper is [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150514064105/http://philoscience.unibe.ch/documents/TexteHS10/bell1964epr.pdf), the equation in question is (15) in page 198 (page 4 of the pdf).

Comment: Let $\vec{c} \approx \vec{b} + \vec{\epsilon}$ for small $|\vec{\epsilon}| = |\vec{b} - \vec{c}|$. Expand $P(\vec{a}, \vec{c}) \equiv P(\vec{a}, \vec{b} + \vec{\epsilon})$ around $P(\vec{a}, \vec{b})$ to first order in $\vec{\epsilon}$. What do you get?

Comment: Affine linear approximation would yield: $P(\vec a ,\vec b+ \vec \varepsilon)\approx P(\vec a ,\vec b) + \mathrm{d}P(\vec a ,\vec b) /\mathrm{d}\vec\varepsilon\cdot \vec\varepsilon$ which then would lead to the inequality $1+P(\vec b,\vec c) \ge |\varepsilon||\mathrm{d}P(\vec a ,\vec b) /\mathrm{d}\vec\varepsilon|$ Hence, the right hand side is of the desired order, correct?

Comment: Correct. Sorry, for whatever reason your message did not show in my queue, happened to check manually. Try perhaps to make messages user-targeted?

Comment: Why would $P$ be continuous or differentiable? It's not assumed anywhere earlier in the paper.